# Container with padding inner element with negative margin not working

Tags: html, css, width, margin, padding

Why does `.column2` with 100% width not 'out-dent' itself with the negative margins?

Why does `.column1` with `auto` width 'out-dent' itself with negative margins as opposed to `.column2`?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 15px;
}

.column1 {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.column2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column1'>hello</div>
  <div class='column2'>hola</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really obvious but can be reasoned as the difference between `width: auto` and `width: 100%`.

1. The `padding` given to `container` rules out any *margin collapsing*.
2. For `column1` as the `width` is *auto* and `display` is *block*, it *fills all available space* it has and when the *negative margins* are applied on top of this, the width self-adjusts.
3. For `column2` as the `width` is 100%, the width will be *computed* to the width of its *containing block* and *negative margins* are applied on it - but the computed `width` can't change now.

See a comparison between *positive* and *negative* `margin`s below. Note that the `width` of `column2` is the same value in all cases.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 15px;
}

.column1 {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.column2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.container.positive > div {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
Negative margin
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column1'>hello</div>
  <div class='column2'>hola</div>
</div>

Positive margin
<div class='container positive'>
  <div class='column1'>hello</div>
  <div class='column2'>hola</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobertRocha was reading some old questions... upvote if the answer helped you, thanks!